# Firebase dynamic link redirection

Tags: firebase-dynamic-links

I'm using [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/rest#create_a_short_link_from_a_long_link) provided by firebase for dynamic link generation. How do I create a link that opens up app and include app specific variables.

Answer (score 1):

It's the same value. If the app is not installed, `link` will be opened in the browser (unless overridden by the `ifl` or `afl` params). If the app IS installed, it will launch and you'll get the contents of `link` delivered to you, which you must then parse out and handle as necessary to accomplish deep linking to content inside the app.

See [here](https://blog.branch.io/is-branch-a-replacement-for-firebase-dynamic-links/) for an implemented example, and a comparison with the simpler 'key:value' approach we use at [Branch.io](https://branch.io) (full disclosure: I'm on the Branch team).